# Why am I not receiving some of the LEGO Harry Potter: Years 1-4 trophies?

Tags: achievements, lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

I've played *LEGO Harry Potter: Years 1-4* through to the end.  I've got most of the trophies, but not all.  I think I've done everything required to get them but it just won't give the the trophy and I can't see how to trigger it.

The **Student Rescue** trophy should be granted when all students in peril are rescued.  The game is stating I've found 50 of 50 but hasn't given me the trophy.

The **Dark Wizards** trophy says I have to buy every version of Voldemort - I've got 167/167 characters and have bought everyone at Madam Malkin's.  Am I missing something?

I've been into Borgin and Burkes and got the last Lord Voldemort character - but to get that I had to find/earn all 200 gold bricks.

I've seen some walkthoughs that suggest there may be glitches that stop you being able to achieve all the achievements.  One recommended taking a back up of your save game regularly - but I haven't, I didn't realise till too late as I didn't look up the walkthoughs till I was stuck.

Have I really got a start a new game and play it through again if I want the above two trophies (and the True Wizard that would follow)?  That means replaying it entirely to get all the Dark Wizards (Lord Voldemort after 200 gold bricks!).

Comment: What system are you playing on?

Comment: On PS3.  Not been online, just me and other half co-oping at various points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are bugs with the co-op mode in *LEGO Harry Potter: Years 1-4*, which can result in any of the "buy all types of characters" trophies not rewarding properly.  I hate to say this, but the only solution is to restart the game from a fresh save and ensure only one player purchases the characters.

From [PS3Trophies.org](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/lego-harry-potter-years-1-4/58669-lego-harry-potter-frequently-asked-questions.html):

> **Q: Help! My Wonderful Weasly/Quidditch Team/Dark Wizards/Animagus Trophy didnt unlock! Why? What can I do?**
>
> A: These trophies are known to glitch if any of the characters needed
>   for the trophy are purchased by the player 2 in co-op mode. There is
>   no known remedy for the situation so far aside from starting the game
>   over for that trophy. The best way to ensure these trophies unlock
>   normally is to make sure player 1 purchases them all. Sometimes it is
>   even better to be safe and have player 2 (if playing Co-op) drop out
>   while you purchase characters.

Comment: Hmm, not the answer I was hoping for but *the* answer nonetheless. Thinking about it, there were times when I, as player 1, dropped out to go do something else and left the co-op player 2 playing. I suspect I've fallen foul of this co-op mode bug.